# active directory using ubuntu server 14.04 and ldap

Tags: server

I find it difficult to get a tutorial for configuration to make active directory using ubuntu 14.04 and ldap.
does anyone have documentation or tutorials that I can follow.

thank you

Comment: You want to make Ubuntu an Domain Controller? AD is *more* than LDAP, so you *should* probably look at [Samba's documentation for how to set up and configure a DC](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller). Also, why 14.04? It's [soon EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: yeah, I want to make Active Directory with Ubuntu, but with Ldap as the backend.
I use ubuntu 14.04 and ldap because this is in accordance with the terms of the assignment that I got from school